# Need eye movement tracking feature on the Android app

Tags: android, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I am new to ML world, so need some guidance. The aim is to track the eye movement via Android front camera preview feed to check if the user is looking straight at the camera or not.

I have tried looking up ML kit use cases for CameraX, but didn't find help on my specific use case. Are there any libraries out there that I can leverage here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check whether you can use getHeadEulerAngleX/Y/Z() for your usecase?

[Example](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/face/Face#public-float-getheadeuleranglex)